# How to connect items in unordered list by lines using HTML

Tags: html, graph, graph-theory

I am working on a genealogy website where I display a person's descendants in an unordered and indented list below their name.

Is there a way to join the bullets in this list by lines in order to form a family tree that branches downwards, using only HTML?

Comment: So you basically need a nested list?

Comment: So you want to draw a line through all bullet points in the list?

Comment: You can not do that with only HTML. You'll have to do it through CSS, and probably a lot of it... Take a look here for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17629815/4315724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very handy guide for this. Here is the fiddle:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wusdqrj/)

HTML:

```
 <ul class="tree"> <li>Animals <ul> <li>Birds</li> <li>Mammals <ul> <li>Elephant</li> <li class="last">Mouse</li> </ul> </li> <li class="last">Reptiles</li></ul>
```

CSS:

```
 ul.tree, ul.tree ul { list-style-type: none; background: #fff url(http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/vline.png) repeat-y; margin: 0; padding: 0; } ul.tree ul { margin-left: 10px; } ul.tree li { margin: 0; padding: 0 12px; line-height: 20px; background: url(http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/node.png) no-repeat; color: #369; font-weight: bold; } ul.tree li.last {
     background: #fff url(http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/lastnode.png) no-repeat;
   }
```

Source:

http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/

Answer (score -3):

```
<ul>
 <li>John Doe
   <ul>
      <li>John Doe's Descendant A</li>
      <li>John Doe's Descendant B</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Jane Somebody
   <ul>
      <li>Jane Somebody's Descendant A</li>
      <li>Jane Somebody's Descendant B</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Or Something a little more involved.

https://jsfiddle.net/hm2uq1zs/

Or:

https://jsfiddle.net/hm2uq1zs/1/