# How to show sets of a project by vertical line and bullet buttons

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Please look at the image

[image]

I have tried this:

[CSS - Vertical line between bullets in an unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629286/css-vertical-line-between-bullets-in-an-unordered-list)

I have got the below result:

[image]

Can you please help me there? I want it to look like the first image.

Comment: Share the code you have tried to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get sort of crazy but you can do it. I don't know if I would suggest this code for a lot of situations, since it's "delicate" and I suspect could be easily disrupted.

```css
.time-chart {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

h3.start {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: .75em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 105px;
}

ul.timeline {
  padding-left: 170px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

ul.timeline li {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  list-style: none;
}

.event {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -160px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.event:after {
  content: "•";
  color: blue;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -21px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.description {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* BORDERS AND BULLETS */

p {
  /*CSS reset*/
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.timeline li {
  position: relative;
  /* so that pseudoelements are positioned relatively to their "li"s*/
  /* use padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom.*/
  margin-bottom: 0;
  /* This overrides previously specified margin-bottom */
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

ul.timeline li:after {
  /* bullets */
  content: "";
}

ul.timeline li:before {
  /* lines */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  /* adjust manually */
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
}

ul.timeline li:first-child:before {
  /* first li's line */
  top: 6px;
  /* moves the line down so that it disappears under the bullet. Adjust manually */
}

ul.timeline li:last-child:before {
  /* last li's line */
  height: 6px;
  /* shorten the line so it goes only up to the bullet. Is equal to first-child:before's top */
}
```

```html
<div class="time-chart ui-widget">
  <h3 class="start">Journey Begins</h3>
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>
      <div class="event">New Product Launch</div>
      <p class="description">Jelly-o pie chocolate cake...</p>
    </li>
    <li class="green">
      <div class="event">New York Times</div>
      <p class="description">Jelly-o pie chocolate cake...</p>
    </li>
    <li class="green">
      <div class="event">New York Times</div>
      <p class="description">Jelly-o pie chocolate cake...</p>
    </li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother. Let me check it. I will let you know. @Twisty

Comment: The code works! Thanks. Can you please tell one thing. How can I make the bullet bigger size. And ring outside it is not perfectly aligned. How can I do it?

Comment: @FahmidaKhan You should become more familiar with CSS. It will help you. Also, you can look at `.event:after` property. it has inherited the `font-size` of 12px, you could define the `font-size` to another value to increase the size of the bullet, as it is text. You will also need to adjust the `width` and `height` if needed.