# Mobile issue , Modify Bootstrap classes or wrong media query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

As you can see right away my media query is becoming a mess. I am creating this timeline with bullets and catching myself writing too many media queries trying to make the bullet align to the timeline

[image]

I am very much in the belief that I made a mistake somewhere. Either in css part on the non-media query, maybe in the position absolute area.i just can't nail the alignment. My requirement is not any specific screen sizes so, I have to make it work on all of them to the best, I am testing by making the browser width smaller and smaller. Is there a bootstrap solution to this? Am I writing the media query in a wrong way?

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap {
  padding: 5rem 0;
 /*========== Media queries ==========*/
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::before {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 26px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 33px;
  top: 2px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  left: 26px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::after {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  left: 28px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-listCount, .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-leftContent {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
  left: 5.2%;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list.active .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: 0;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -1.4%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: 1.4%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -4.2%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -0.2%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -0.2%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -0.4%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 570px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: 0%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 533px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -0.5%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -1.3%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -2.5%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -3.4%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 370px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -4.1%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
    left: -5.4%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">


</head>

<body>
    
    <section class="project-methodology-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-leftContent">
                        <div class="pr-5">
                            <h2>title</h2>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, eum deserunt perferendis asperiores esse temporibus est numquam repellat doloremque suscipit enim quod nisi nam cum ea quam expedita quidem velit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="img-fluid pt-5 pb-5 pr-5" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-rightContent pt-5">
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">1</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">2</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">3</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 
 

</body>

</html>
```

I am a beginner in CSS and mobile first, here is my code so far

Comment: you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629286/css-vertical-line-between-bullets-in-an-unordered-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was so simple, i removed all media query and used px instead of % on

> .project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent:before

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap {
  padding: 5rem 0;
 /*========== Media queries ==========*/
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::before {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 26px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 33px;
  top: 2px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  left: 26px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::after {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  left: 28px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-listCount, .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-leftContent {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
  left: 35px
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list.active .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 1;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">


</head>

<body>
    
    <section class="project-methodology-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-leftContent">
                        <div class="pr-5">
                            <h2>title</h2>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, eum deserunt perferendis asperiores esse temporibus est numquam repellat doloremque suscipit enim quod nisi nam cum ea quam expedita quidem velit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="img-fluid pt-5 pb-5 pr-5" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-rightContent pt-5">
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">1</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">2</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">3</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 
 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this approach: https://www.bootply.com/KBKYt3w6Z7

Basically, you don't need all of those media queries for your timeline if you can adjust your markup so that the :before and :after are on the same element, you can then target both the line and the red dot at that same position/level.

In the example I've changed your markup to use a `ul > li` instead and changed it so that the timeline CSS is on the list items.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

with minimum effort,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lvgwcp?file=style.css

I have removed all the css and got what I want for timeline only. so for your project add whatever you need. this is responsive for minimum 360px width device.

Also I have made some html changes, which is I added `<div class="project-content">` this div.

**No media query.**

For any clarification comment please.

Also without any ui I separated bullets from timeline. if you need it can align with css left property.